# Symfony 2.1 configuration of FOSUserBundle 'Class 'FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle' not found in app/AppKernel.php

Tags: php, windows, symfony, wamp, fosuserbundle

I am using symfony on Windows and I tried to configure FOSUserBundle as described in the [official documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md)

When I run `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` I get this message:

```
Class 'FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle' not found in app/AppKernel.php line 24;
```

I configured the AppKernel.php as I should:

```
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        // The rest
        new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
    );

    return $bundles;
}
```

My`FOSUserBundle.php` file is located at `vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle`

Comment: Are you using symfony 2.0 or 2.1? Composer or vendors? If vendors, did you update the autoload.php and clear the cache?

Comment: Show the autoload.php file located in the app directory

Comment: @Sgoettschkes question says 2.1, so he'll be using composer

Comment: Did you launch "$ php bin/vendors install"?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to register a namespace also in autoload ex.:

```
$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
        //all the rest
        'FOS' => $vendor_dir . '/bundles',
));
```

It should be done by composer here. So run `php composer update`. If you're using cache like `APC` remember to restart the `apache`.
But remember that the APC is loaded from bootstrap.php.cache witch is generated by `php composer update`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I found out that the FOSUserBundle was not properly installed. You should delete your /vendor/friendsofsymfony/ directory and then run the update the bundle using:

```
php composer.phar update friendsofsymfony/user-bundle
```

This worked for me. I hope it helps someone else having the same problem.